# How to restrict access to edit attachments in lists?

Tags: wss-3.0, security, attachments

We have Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 SP 3 (12.0.0.6608 from CA) on Windows 2003 Server R2 EE. In the main we use our WSS as sort of book of problems. And by book of problems, i mean that there is one List called *Tasks*. There is one user that can access to create tasks items. The other users can only write comments and attach files. There are some restrictions such as hide columns, hide views that we have implemented with [BoostSolutions](http://www.boostsolutions.com). And there are some restriction such as unable to delete attachments from list that i have implemented with SharePoint Event Handlers.

Our problem step-by-step:

1. User Andrew attach **file1.docx** to List item (**task1**)
2. User Andrew click Save the **task1** item is saved
3. User Andrew open **task1** and see **file1.docx** in attachments
4. User Andrew open **file1.docx** directly from his browser (in fact in this case Microsoft Word is running) - as i understood **file1.docx** opens only for reading
5. When user Andrew click on Save As (right in Microsoft Word) it can access to folder with  this attachment (**file1.docx**) and other attachments which was attached to **task1** item earlier. Then user Andrew can delete them, re-write them and etc.

Can we restrict access to the rewriting and deleting attached files?